# How to push N th array in react readux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to push into N th array item in react redux. But it does not push also does not give any error.

in the function i tried to like this

```
const id = action.payload.container_id;

console.log("id", id);

// state.containers
let key = 0;
state.containers = state.containers.map((cont) => {
  console.log("key", key);
  if (cont.info.id === id) {
    console.log("found container atrr", state.containers[key].info.title);
    state.containers[key].info.attributes.push({
      id: action.payload.container_attr_id,
      value: action.payload.data.value,
      name: action.payload.data.name,
    });
  }
  key = key + 1;
});
```

Comment: You have to return something from the map function

Comment: yes i missed that. Thanks. Can you give me wide explanation

Answer (score 0):

I found my error. Needs to return

```
const id = action.payload.container_id;
  console.log("id", id);
  console.log("action payload", action.payload);
  // state.containers
    let key = 0
    state.containers = state.containers.map((cont) => {
      console.log("key", key);
      if (cont.info.id === id) {
        console.log("found container atrr", state.containers[key].info.title);
        
        state.containers[key].info.attributes.push({
          id: action.payload.container_attr_id,
          value: action.payload.value,
          name: action.payload.name,
        });
      }
      key = key + 1
      **return cont**
    });
```